# HTTPS request restarts NodeMCU

Tags: https, lua, tls1.2, nodemcu

NodeMCU Info:

```
> NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
> branch: dev
> SSL: true
> modules: crypto,file,gpio,http,net,node,sjson,tmr,uart,wifi,tls
> powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1
> commit: d5aca39f485bf46e6d77b7fb05eaf71b8ea51bee
> Build type: integer -- tried float, same error
> LFS : disabled
```

Build bin [file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/s27sh44lcmwqjz4/nodemcu-dev-11-modules-2018-11-23-23-36-06-integer.bin/file)

When I requested `HTTPS` request before adding the `tls` module it returned code `-1` after I added `tls` module requesting `HTTPS` restarts the NodeMCU.

The code I used to send request.

```
   print(node.heap()) -- 31824
   http.request("https://www.google.com", "HEAD", "", "", 
   function(code, data)
      if (code < 0) then
        print("HTTP request failed")
      else
        print(code, data)
      end
    end)
```

and I tried the net module.

```
   print(node.heap()) -- 31824
   srv = tls.createConnection()
   srv:on("receive", function(sck, c) print(c) end)
   srv:on("connection", function(sck, c)
   sck:send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
end)
   srv:connect(443,"google.com")
```

I got the same restart reason for both codes.

```
HTTP client: hostname=google.com
HTTP client: port=443
HTTP client: method=GET
HTTP client: path=/
HTTP client: DNS request
HTTP client: DNS pending
> HTTP client: DNS found google.com 172.217.18.46
client handshake start.
Fatal exception 0(IllegalInstructionCause):
epc1=0x4027ca20, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x402993e7, depc=0x00000000
þ
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,x) -- sometimes x is 0, 6 or 7

load 0x40100000, len 26104, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0xc0
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2332, room 0 
tail 12
chksum 0x3c
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load 0x3ffe891c, len 136, room 12 
tail 12
chksum 0x56
csum 0x56
```

in the net moudle code the restart happens when `srv:connect(443,"google.com")` is called and shows one additional line `RecvHold, By pespconn,find conn_msg fail`

Comment: I'm not surprised that `sck:send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com` fails as the amount of data Google returns is way more than what fits into the device heap. However, with `http.request("https://www.google.com", "HEAD"` this shouldn't happen as no payload is returned.

Comment: @MarcelStör `http.request("https://www.google.com", "HEAD"` should return at least the response code which is 200 is this case, and I tried with other sites same result, though I overcome this, see answers

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I said, "no payload" -> only HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date in your error is because of something you executed recently, I suggest that you set the time to a more recent one. If your time has drifted too much your OS cannot operate normally. Set time manuelly if NTP refuse your connection. How to set RTC [rtctime module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/rtctime/), but also look at sntp module or other relevant ones.

Comment: If you type ”date” in your terminal it should show current date properly. Assuming that is correct download latest src, or file a bug report there.

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this problem by building the same `SDK Firmware 2.2.1` with **Docker** with the same modules and same configuration, can't control cases and lines to debug in the **Cloud Build** version so cant know what exactly went wrong in the **Cloud Build**.

The Docker Firmware info

```
NodeMCU 2.2.0.0 built with Docker provided by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 4095c408e6a8cc9718cb06007b408d0aad15d9cd
    SSL: true
    Build type: integer
    LFS: disabled
    modules: crypto,file,gpio,http,net,node,sjson,tls,tmr,uart,wifi
 build created on 2018-11-29 17:45
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(6ab97e9)
```

Comment: In your initial description the Lua prompt you're showing looks odd: commit is missing an so are build type and LFS. "When I requested HTTPS request before adding the tls module it returned code -1" -> when you select SSL in the cloud builder the TLS module is added automatically.

Comment: @MarcelStör I edited the build info in my question and uploaded the Build bin file I used on ESP8266 12F. By added TLS module I meant selecting TLS/SSL support provided by mbed TLS choice

Comment: All is fine with the cloud builder. I just built a firmware with the same configuration and the test code works just fine. Using the HTTP snippet prints '200'. The one with the net module prints the complete HTTP 301 response from Google. Here's the binary: https://transfer.sh/nmiCs/nodemcu-dev-11-modules-2018-11-30-18-40-43-integer.bin

Comment: @MarcelStör Tried and the same exact error. However, its not the power bcs im using a very stable circuit. I used NodeMCU Flasher, the build goes to 0x00000 and DEFAULT to 0x3FC000, ESP8266 12-F ai thinker